# Are Angularjs services singleton?

Tags: angularjs

In the [reference](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.creating_services)I read:

> Lastly, it is important to realize that all Angular services are
>   application singletons. This means that there is only one instance of
>   a given service per injector.

but with this simple code seems not to be a singleton

```
'use strict';
            angular.module('animal', [])
                .factory('Animal',function(){
                    return function(vocalization){
                        return {
                            vocalization:vocalization,
                            vocalize : function () {
                                console.log('vocalize: ' + this.vocalization);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });    
                angular.module('app', ['animal'])
                    .factory('Dog', function (Animal) {
                        return Animal('bark bark!');
                    })
                    .factory('Cat', function (Animal) {
                        return Animal('meeeooooow');
                    })
                .controller('MainCtrl',function($scope,Cat,Dog){
                     $scope.cat = Cat;
                     $scope.dog = Dog;
                     console.log($scope.cat);
                     console.log($scope.dog);
                    //$scope.cat = Cat;
                });
```

I'm a little confused can you explain me what's the matter ?

**UPDATE 1**
May be I'm not the sharpest tool in the shed
but afer the @Khanh TO reply it would be a better
explanation in the reference it's not very clear.

**UPDATE 2**

```
'use strict';
            angular.module('animal', [])
                .factory('Animal',function(){
                        return {
                            vocalization:'',
                            vocalize : function () {
                                console.log('vocalize: ' + this.vocalization);
                            }
                        }

                });
                angular.module('dog', ['animal'])
                    .factory('Dog', function (Animal) {
                        Animal.vocalization = 'bark bark!';
                        Animal.color = 'red';
                        return Animal;
                    });

                angular.module('cat', ['animal'])
                   .factory('Cat', function (Animal) {
                        Animal.vocalization = 'meowwww';
                        Animal.color = 'white';
                        return Animal;
                    });
                 angular.module('app', ['dog','cat'])
                .controller('MainCtrl',function($scope,Cat,Dog){
                     $scope.cat = Cat;
                     $scope.dog = Dog;
                     console.log($scope.cat);
                     console.log($scope.dog);
                    //$scope.cat = Cat;
                });
```

BOOM it's a singleton !

**UPDATE 3**

But if you do like

```
'use strict';
            angular.module('animal', [])
                .factory('Animal',function(){
                    return function(vocalization){
                        return {
                            vocalization:vocalization,
                            vocalize : function () {
                                console.log('vocalize: ' + this.vocalization);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });    
                angular.module('app', ['animal'])
                    .factory('Dog', function (Animal) {
                        function ngDog(){
                            this.prop = 'my prop 1';
                            this.myMethod = function(){
                                console.log('test 1');
                            }
                        }
                        return angular.extend(Animal('bark bark!'), new ngDog());
                    })
                    .factory('Cat', function (Animal) {
                        function ngCat(){
                            this.prop = 'my prop 2';
                            this.myMethod = function(){
                                console.log('test 2');
                            }
                        }
                        return angular.extend(Animal('meooow'), new ngCat());
                    })
                .controller('MainCtrl',function($scope,Cat,Dog){
                     $scope.cat = Cat;
                     $scope.dog = Dog;
                     console.log($scope.cat);
                     console.log($scope.dog);
                    //$scope.cat = Cat;
                });
```

it works

Comment: Reference doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It's singleton, there is only one object, but is injected into many places. (objects are passed by reference to a method)

All your `Animal` are object pointers referring to **the same animal object** which is a **function** in your case.
Your `Cat` and `Dog` are objects constructed by this function.

Comment: because of I've got a php background it's sound a little odd for me. If in a php application I use a db singleton connection I can have only one connection and that's why singleton could be evil

Comment: @Whisher: I updated my answer with information about `objects are passed by reference to a method`. Hope it's clearer for you.

Comment: @Whisher: what is not clear for you? In your update 3, you create a `new object` using Animal function and extend that object with a new `ngDog`, `ngCat`. There are no modifications to `Animal` which is a function.

Comment: In the update 2 the service is singleton the set up of Dog rewrite Cat. Cat has the same prop/method of Dog.

Comment: @Whisher: in update 2, your `Animal`, `Dog`, `Cat` refer to the same object.

Comment: Ok I got it :). Sorry to bother you again and again but could you give me an example without using angular.extend ? Be patience :)

Comment: @Whisher: in your update 3, actually you don't need `angular.extend`, you just need to ensure you return a `new object`, not a reference to an existing one.

Comment: Ouf, sorry I don't understand :( the only think I can think of is passing Animal as DI

Comment: @Whisher: yes, you pass Animal as DI. The `Animal` you get as a DI is a `reference to the singleton Animal object`, if you modify anything using this reference, all other places injected with this `Animal` will notice the change.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, service is singleton. The following code log only one "M" to console:

```
function M() { console.log('M'); }
function M1(m) { console.log(1); }
function M2(m) { console.log(2); }
angular.module('app', [])
.service('M', M)
.service('M1', ['M', M1])
.service('M2', ['M', M2])
.controller('MainCtrl',function(M1, M2){});
```

[run it in jsbin](http://jsbin.com/bisozajiza/1/edit?html,js,console#J:L2)

Answer (score 3):

Let me give an example about singletons in AngularJS.
Lets assume that we have 2 controllers used in different part of our single page application:

```
myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$log', function($scope, $log) {

    $log.main = 'First Var';
    $log.log($log);

}]);
```

So now if we went to the page that is controlled via `mainController` controller, we will see this at the log:

[image]

As you see, the log object now contain my first variable.

Now here is my second controller:

```
myApp.controller('secondController', ['$scope', '$log', '$routeParams', function($scope, $log, $routeParams) {

    $log.secondVar = 'Second Var';
    $log.log($log);

}]);
```

So if you click on the second page that is controlled, you will see this:

[image]

Now get back to the first page:

[image]

What do you conclude about those 3 steps ?

Their is one `$log` object injected to the app. And as Tony Alicea said: This is a big memory save.

So this service, is called one time, and each time we are adding new variables and parameters to the same object and not adding different objects for different parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Your example uses a `factory`, not a `service`. Note that `provider` is part of the game as well.

The best learning resource so far:

[AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angular-js-service-vs-provider-vs-factory)

There is an enlightening explanation by Miško Hevery and a practical example of `factory`, `service` and `provider`. **Highly recommend**.

Comment: I've used factory for a user case but angularjs reference refer to service as a whole (factory,service,provider)

Comment: The factory/service distinction has nothing to do with it. The "factory" and "service" patterns are both just different ways of constructing a service. _All_ services are "singletons", regardless of how they're constructed. The issue with @Whisher's original example is that the function that constructs the Animal service doesn't return an object - it returns another function. So the Animal "service" is actually a function - still a "singleton", just not an object. The Animal "singleton" function is then used to construct the Dog and Cat services, which in this case are objects. (whew!)