# Service singleton across all controllers

Tags: angularjs

If I have the following :

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    {{vm.name_from_service}}
</div>
....
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    {{vm.name_from_service}}
</div>
```

Lets say they both pull the name_from_service value from a factory/service , is it correct to assume that the same service singleton is being used across both mainCtrl controller instances ?

**Note that mainCtrl is used twice.**

---

controller code snippet :

```
$scope.vm.name_from_service = someservice.getName();
```

---

Snippet #2 :

Both ng-view and the immediate div below use the same service to retrieve name_from_service, however name_from_service is only update in one place.

```
 <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
         section 1
        {{vm.name_from_service}}
 </div>

 <div id="ngviewcontainer" ng-view=""></div>
```

Also I am not using any asynchronous ajax calls to retrieve name_from_service so angular should be aware of the changes.

I've tried using $timeout and $apply() . No dice .

**I refactored and separated out unrelated logic into a separate controller and fixed the issue**. Still a bit confused as to why only one of the two values were updating evening though both were supposedly pulling from the same service.

Comment: what do you mean by updating in a one place?

Comment: @PankajParkar updates in the markup rendered by ng-view but not the div above it in section 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it would be the same, unless some digest cycle synchronizations problems. 
There are situations, where you set a variable like this:

```
$scope.vm.name_from_service = someservice.getName();
```

But if you work with promises and **$http** calls, then sometime you have to watch changes in singletons manually using $watch. That's the situation where both controllers can have different values.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, [that is why it is called singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

> singleton pattern is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation
>   of a class to one object

Also have a look at nearly the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496331/angularjs-are-service-singleton)

Answer (score 1):

You're using one controller - mainCtrl.  Your controller can use multiple services.  However, you cannot use different services under the same name in a controller. So yes, you're using the same service.