# How to inject 2 different instances of a module in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I have a crudService.js file:

```
crudService.module('genericCrudService', ['$http', '$log', 'config',  function ($http, $log, config) {
        ....
        return {
            setSomeAttribute: function(m) {
                // set attribute
            }
        }
    }]);
```

And then I have a module that need to differently configured instances of this crud service:

```
module.factory('Task', ['genericCrudService','genericCrudService', function (service, actionService) {
        ...
        return {
           init: function(p) {
               service.setSomeAttribute('a');
               actionService.setSomeAttribute('b');
           }
        }
    }]);
```

But then I noticed when trying to use the *service* variable, that its attribute is set to 'a'. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not really clear what you are trying to do or what expectations are

Comment: As others have mentioned, these services are singletons by design, and by embracing this model, it enables a powerful method of communication within a module. For example, you can inject your service in one controller, subscribe to an event, store data, or change a variable on the service and in another controller you can access that data or trigger the event. In Angular 2, this is your means of communicating between your components because the scope is gone. I believe whatever it is you need to do can still be done with a singleton, you need only rethink your approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular services [are singletons](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#factory-recipe) which are cached on the first injection:

> All services in Angular are singletons. That means that the injector uses each recipe at most once to create the object. The injector then caches the reference for all future needs.

`genericCrudService` refers to the same service, injecting it as `service` and `actionService` variables results in having the instance of `genericCrudService` service in both variables, `service === actionService`.

If a service should get a new instance only in some cases, service instance may get a method (e.g. `factory` or `getInstance`) that returns a new instance of the object:

```
  app.factory('service', () => {
    function Service() {
      this.method = ...;
      this.factory = () => new Service;
    }

    return new Service;
  });

  ...
  var serviceInstance = service.factory();
```

If a service should get a new instance everywhere, it should return a factory or constructor function that will be instantiated manually:

```
  app.factory('Service', () => function () {
    this.method = ...;       
  });

  ...
  var serviceInstance = new Service;
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that because an angular service is a singleton... Have a look on that post it explains it very well ;) [Are Angularjs services singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496331/angularjs-are-service-singleton)

You can also have a look on that [AngularJS: Service vs provider vs factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15666048/angularjs-service-vs-provider-vs-factory). Maybe you'll find a way to do what you want ;)