# How to create singleton service for timer in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, singleton, intervals

I am doing a project in angularjs (1.x). My requirement is that I need to count the number of seconds elapsed.

For that, I have written a code using $interval service in my controller which is working perfectly fine.

Now , since this code is shared by many objects, so I thought to make it singleton. How can we do so?

Below is my code inside controller:

```
scope.timeDiff = 0;
 var intervalId = $interval(function(){
           scope.timeDiff += 1000; 
        },1000);

 scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
           $interval.clear(intervalId);
 });
```

I have tried to create a service of timer like this:

```
angular.module('myModule').factory('customTimer', ['$interval','$rootScope',
  function ($interval,$rootScope) {
     var timerId, defaultInterval = 1000;     
     return {
       startTimer: function (timeDiff) {
        $interval(function(){
           timeDiff += 1000;
        },1000);
        return timeDiff;
       }
     };
}]);
```

And then I try to call this service in my controller like this:

```
scope.timeDiff = customTimer.startTimer( scope.timeDiff);        
console.log( "new timediff:",scope.timeDiff );
```

While timeDiff is updating in my timer service, but controller is always getting 0. What could be the reason?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are Angularjs services singleton?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21496331/are-angularjs-services-singleton)

Comment: Angular service is singleton, you don't need to make it singleton

Comment: @huanfeng Please see the edits

Comment: @KaustubhKhare: Please see the edits

Comment: In your service, you are returning `timeDiff`. It will return immediately. when you called `startTimer` function. It will not wait till 1 sec.

Comment: @KaustubhKhare could you please help me how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Explain me more about when you need count of no of secs?

Comment: Actually not quite understand you question, what's the begin point and end point?

Comment: Actually, from backend I am getting some information periodically..So I need to count the seconds elapsed between arrival of information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all angular service and factory is already singleton.

The only problem is a synchronization problem.

Its asynchronous call, so you have to ensure it by using callback or promise.

In controller add the following methods:

```
$scope.callback = function(retTime) {
  console.log( "new timediff:",retTime);
}
$scope.timeDiff = customTimer.startTimer( scope.timeDiff, $scope.callback);   

$scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
       customTimer.stopTimer();
});
```

The factory can be written as follows:

```
angular.module('myModule').factory('customTimer', ['$interval','$rootScope',
  function ($interval,$rootScope) {
     var timerId, defaultInterval = 1000;     
     return {
       startTimer: function (timeDiff, callback) {
        timerId = $interval(function(){
           timeDiff += 1000;
        // This if block will ensure your controller callback called after the value of time diff is updated.
           if(callback) {
              callback(timeDiff)
           }
        },1000);
        return timeDiff;
       },
       stopTimer: function () {
         $interval.cancel(timerId);
       }
     };
}]);
```

The angular service can be written as follows:

```
angular.module('myModule').service('customTimer', ['$interval','$rootScope',
  function ($interval,$rootScope) {
     var self = this;
     self.defaultInterval = 1000;     

       self.startTimer = function (timeDiff, callback) {
        self.timerId = $interval(function(){
           timeDiff += 1000;
        // This if block will ensure your controller callback called after the value of time diff is updated.
           if(callback) {
              callback(timeDiff)
           }
        },1000);
        return timeDiff;
       }
       self.stopTimer = function () {
         $interval.cancel(self.timerId);
       }

}]);
```

Comment: Your solution is working fine. Thank you so much. Could you please edit the code of service and add the code for destroying/clear the interval ?

Comment: Please check the answer is updated with destroying and clear the interval