# Extending a service provider (provider)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to extend a service provider; more specifically $routeProvider from the ngRoute module

my extended provider looks like this:

```
angular
    .module('myapp')
    .provider('customRoute', customRoute)

function customRoute($routeProvider) {

    var extendedProvider = angular.extend({}, $routeProvider, {
        // Customization here
    });

    // These will print almost identical objects
    console.log(extendedProvider); 
    console.log($routeProvider);

    this.$get = function() {
        return extendedProvider;
    }
}
```

The config of the routes looks something like this:

```
angular
    .module('myapp')
    .config(Routes);

function Routes(customRouteProvider, $routeProvider) {

    /* This will print an object that looks the same as 
       the ones printed in the provider definition */
    console.log($routeProvider);

    /* This object does not look like the $routeProvider any more :( */
    console.log(customRouteProvider);

    customRouteProvider
        .when('/', {
             templateUrl: 'path/to/some/template.html',
            controller: 'SomeController',
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}
```

I've read this thread:

[how can i extend a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293943/how-can-i-extend-a-service)

But they only talk about extending the "factory"-service

Can someone explain what is happening here? Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to extend `$routeProvider` your `customRoute` function must return extended provider object:

```
function customRoute($routeProvider) {

    var extendedProvider = angular.extend({}, $routeProvider, {
        // Customization here
        mergeRoutes: function() {}
    });

    return extendedProvider;
}
```

After that you could for example you new custom method `customRouteProvider.mergeRoutes`:

```
customRouteProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'path/to/some/template.html',
        controller: 'SomeController',
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    })
    .mergeRoutes({ ... });
```

**Demo** to play: http://plnkr.co/edit/mht94RFLScz2jHCwPcai?p=preview

For your purposes you don't need to mess with `this.$get`, you just need to add some new methods to `$routeProvider`. `this.$get` returns a service object instance/constructor for corresponding provider service (`$route` in case of `$routeProvider`).