# Inheritance in services

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following module :

```
angular.module('project.itemServices', ['project.cacheFactory', 'project.dataProvider'])

.run(function() {
        ISvc = new function () {
            this.endpoint = '';
            this.name = 'foo';
            this.items = {};
            this.clean = function () {
                cacheFactory.clear(this.name);
                items = {};
            };
            this._store = null;
            this.populate = function () {
                cacheFactory.look('fetch', this.endpoint, this.name).then(function (data) {
                    this._store(data);
                })
            };
        };
    }
)

.service('catListSvc', function()
{
    this.prototype = ISvc.prototype;
})

.run(function(catListSvc)
{
    console.log(catListSvc.name);
});
```

I want all my services in this module to inherit from the ISvc object, and then implement it's own `_store` method, this service is intended for sharing data between controllers.

I don't know how to do this, when trying to `console.log(catListSvc.name)`, `undefined` comes up.

I tried several things eg. `Objects.create(ISvc.prototype)`, but doesn't work.

Any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: `this.prototype` doesn't do anything. To setup inheritance you need to set the `prototype` property of the constructor to an object that is attached to the prototype you want to inherit.

Comment: Could you write an example please? I'm confused.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, angular 1 is not my thing, I'm just explaining where your main problem lies. See http://blog.mgechev.com/2013/12/18/inheritance-services-controllers-in-angularjs/

Comment: Found kind of an answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15293943/how-can-i-extend-a-service, but I wonder if I can do it the pure JS way.

Comment: See https://gist.github.com/boneskull/6011707

Comment: Nice, that's what I was looking for, you can answer if you want.

Comment: @MaximeB It is not possible to apply inheritance to this module only because Angular doesn't differ modules on service level. The example above won't work that good if `baseService` is defined in other file (and often it does). This means that JS modules (`require`/`import`) should be used together with Angular modules, your question doesn't cover these requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic pattern for service inheritance that may be spread across several JS files requires only Angular DI is

```
// service is PascalCased and returns a constructor
function BaseProjectService(...deps...) { ... }

app.value('BaseProjectService', BaseProjectService);

// service is camelCased and returns an instance
app.factory('someProjectService', ['BaseProjectService', ...deps..., function (BaseProjectService, ...deps...) {
  function SomeProjectService(...deps...) { 
    // is a super constuctor, since SomeProjectService has got no own prototype
    this.constructor(...deps); 
    ...
  }
  SomeProjectService.prototype = BaseProjectService.prototype;
  return new SomeProjectService(...deps...);
}]);
```

The downside is that factory functions and not classes are responsible for deps annotation and injection, this results in WET code

This pattern may become subsequently more complicated when child services need their own prototypes, this is where ES6 classes should be taken into account.